# Why does my useMemo hook not work prevent unneccesary computations in this use case?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am struggling to make my useMemo use case work.

Perhaps I am wrong, but I am expecting the first click to take a long time and it isn't. Even when I increased the size of the items array to 99 million.

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";

const items = new Array(1_999_999).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
  return {
    id: i,
    isSelected: i === 1_999_998,
  };
});

export default function UseMemoExample() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);


  const selectedItem = useMemo(() => {
    return items.find((item) => item.isSelected);
  }, [items]);  


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>useMemo</h2>
      <p>Count is {count}</p>
      <p>Selected Item is {selectedItem?.id}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the *items* variable is declared within the *UseMemoExample* function, it cannot handle the spamming of the increment button. This I assume means the useMemo is doing the lengthy computations each click.

When declared outside of the *UseMemoExample* function, it effortlessly loads the first click, which I am expecting it not to, and can hanle pamming of the increment button. Which tells me useMemo isn't doing anything.

Comment: I ran it in a sandbox without problem, perhaps the memo is taking long comparing each frame that the [items] are the same (and they're really long arrays)

Comment: @EdwynZN I followed a youtube tutorial which showed it working fine with 29,999,999 objects in the array, so I am not sure that is it

Comment: In the current implementation, `items` is created when you load your app. So it behaves like static data and is never recomputed later. There is no even sense to place `items` in the dependency array because it never changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run `eslint` on your example code, you’d get the following error:

> 16:6 - React Hook useMemo has an unnecessary dependency: 'items'.
> Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values
> like 'items' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't
> re-render the component.

This is part of the explanation for why the initial click is not taking a long time.

As you know `useMemo` has 2 parameters. One is a function. The second is an array of dependencies. `useMemo` is used to cache the result of the parameter function. This is useful, of course, when the function is expensive (which you have tried to make, in your example code). The result of the function is cached as long as the dependencies do not change (React uses [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) for comparing instances of the dependencies). Since you have declared the `items` array outside of the component and nothing changes it, before the component re-renders, the result of the function is cached, so `selectedItem` is not re-calculated.

If you would change your items array before the component re-renders (let’s say on your button’s click action), the `selectedItem` will be re-calculated.

If you declare the items array inside your `UseMemoExample`, it is normal for the `selectedItem` to be re-calculated on every click. That’s because the component re-renders when the count is increased. When the component re-renders, the `items` array is re-created, so the dependency that you declared for your `useMemo` has changed. Why does it consider that the array changed? Well, React uses `Object.is` to compare the `items` dependency that you gave as a parameter on the initial render, with the `items` that you give as a parameter on the next render. They’re different instances of the array, so `Object.is` returns `false`, even if the `items` has the same values. In order to **not** re-calculate `selectedItem` on every click, you can make your items part of the component’s state:

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState(new Array(1_999_999).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
    return {
      id: i,
      isSelected: i === 1_999_998,
    };
}));
```

or “memoize” the array between re-renders:

```js
const items = useMemo(() => {
    return new Array(1_999_999).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
      return {
        id: i,
        isSelected: i === 1_999_998,
      };
    });
}, []);
```

If `items` does not change between re-renders, `selectedItem` will not be re-calculated. If `items` does change, it will be re-calculated.

I’m not saying these are good solutions for the problem that you’re trying to solve. I’m just explaining how `useMemo` works, in the example code that you provided.

I recommend reading the [`useMemo` documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo). It is quite instructive.